# Using a Promise in a Node.js web server to handle requests

Tags: node.js, express, es6-promise

Does it make sense to use a promise to handle a request as shown in the following code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    return new Promise(async function (resolve) {
                       await someLongRunningProcess();
                       resolve();
     })
     .then() {
        res.end();
     };
});

// Start the server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3002;
app.listen(PORT, () => {

});
```

Would there be any performance improvement of using a Promise, especially if a long running process needs to be handled for each request? Since Node.js is just a single thread, using a Promise might just be an illusion that it increases performance.

Answer (score 1):

Each promise has a cost [in terms of memory and execution logic](https://www.promisejs.org/implementing/). It is not free.

So every useless promise adds overhead and possible bugs to your request flow.

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  /**
   * Promise doesn't not support this signature.
   * You must use function (resolve, reject){}.
   *
   * If you have an error in this function, you will
   * get an UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning
   */
  return new Promise(async function (resolve) {
    /**
     * if you are awaiting `someLongRunningProcess`,
     * you have already a promise so creating a new
     * one add overhead.
     */
    await someLongRunningProcess()
    resolve()
  })
    .then(() => {
      res.end()
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      /**
       * to avoid UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning and memory leak,
       * be sure to add always a .catch in your promise chain
      */
      res.status(500).end()
    })
})
```

So you can rewrite:

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  someLongRunningProcess()
    .then(() => { res.end() })
    .catch((error) => { res.status(500).end() })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Performance should be about the same as any equivalent code using callbacks. Either way it should be fairly fast, as Node internally uses libuv for nonblocking IO, so having a single thread isn't usually an issue for Node servers.

Comment: But what if my long running process is more CPU intensive and less IO intensive? Would a Promise make any difference? If Node is only giving me a benefit on IO, does using Promises make any sense?

Comment: A Promise is really just an object wrapping a callback. The performance is about the same. It's up to you if you want to use Promises, though I would recommend it.

Comment: If you have a huge blocking CPU operation it will block whether it's called synchronously, with callbacks or with promises. Either chop the operation up into chunks if that's possible or run the calculation in a child process or worker thread: these will resolve a callback or promise (your pick) with the result.

Comment: I'm only familiar with worker threads being supported in the browser. Are you saying that Node can operate with a worker thread when running on the backend? If that's true, can you point me to a link that shows more on how that is done? Thanks!

Comment: While not a tutorial, [the documentation page for Worker Threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#worker_threads_worker_threads) has enough examples that, if you're familiar with how it works in the browser, you'll be able to figure it out. You create a separate file with your code, then run `const wrkr = new Worker(pathToFile);`. The 'default' is to use events/callbacks. Use `const {once} = require('events'); const msg = await once(wrkr, 'message');` to 'promisify' it.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Oddly, the site nodejs.dev, which I was using makes no mention of worker threads.